# Populate column from zigzag cells in Excel

Tags: excel

I have these cells in Excel numbered 1 to 24:

[image]

And I want to populate that column (in a different sheet) with the same 1 - 24 numbers from the first sheet:

[image]

So that if I change a number in sheet one, it's reflected in sheet 2.

It's ridiculously easy to do if they were both columns and relatively simple if one sequential row and clolumns but this zigzag is confusing me. Could do it in VBA but could I do it using plain excel?

Comment: So you want a formula that will bring in the values of the cells below or above the numbers in your first picture?

Comment: Transpose the actual numbers to that column. I'll reuse the same formula for the data from the boxes in between to populate an other column :)

Answer (score 2):

Use this formula that uses an IF to determine which INDEX/MATCH formula to use:

```
=IF(MOD(E16,2)=1,INDEX($8:$8,MATCH(E16,$7:$7,0)),INDEX($10:$10,MATCH(E16,$11:$11,0)))
```

[image]

Comment: I suppose it would work as well if the column is actually in a different sheet?

Comment: @JulioQc yes it would you would just need to adjust the references.

Comment: Ok this works for the data in between but I actually want to populate the index (1-2-3-4-5-6-7-etc). Can't use MOD for those, right?